# Why isn't HttpUtility class being recognised?

Tags: .net, vb.net, http, urlencode

I am trying to call the static `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` in my VB.NET project, but the IDE is not recognising the class saying that it is not declared.

I have imported the namespaces `System.Net` and `System.Web` to the project.

I also have the following at the top of the file:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using Framework 4.0, be careful to use FULL, not client profile, for which you don't have that class...

Comment: Do you have a reference to the System.Web assembly? Are you by any chance using something like .NET 4.0 client profile?

Comment: @JonSkeet: using NET 2.0. Have imported `System.Web` namespace and used `Imports System.Web` at top of file.

Comment: @PaulLassiter: Please add that information to the question, as it's pretty vital information (and suggests that everything really *should* work...)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Web.dll` to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember to click on the "Refresh" icon button for the applicable project in Solution Explorer after adding a new "Imports" line.

Doing that can remove the squiggly lines from under the new "Imports" statement.