# Can't Download Wikipedia Article

Tags: c#

I have a C# Console Based app (Windows 10, VS2015) and I want to download the raw text from two Wikipedia articles. The Wikipedia URLs contain umlauts and one is causing me some trouble. Here is the code just for getting the web response:

```
WebRequest.Create("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albrecht_Dürer").GetResponse();
WebRequest.Create("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dürer's_Rhinoceros").GetResponse();
WebRequest.Create("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durer's_Rhinoceros").GetResponse();
```

The third response is for testing purposes and is the same as the second, except I replace the 'ü' with 'u'.  So the first response works fine, the second fails, and the third works.    At first I thought it was just the umlaut, but if that were the case then the first response wouldn't work. The error I'm receiving on the second response is:

```
System.Net.WebException: Too many automatic redirections were attempted.
```

Also, all three of these responses work when I test them out on my Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: I have also found that the suffix `The_Farm_(Miró)` works but `Miró's Chicago` fails. This seems to suggest that failure occurs if there is both a diacritic character AND a single inverted comma.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the url using `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`. You can also try to use `System.Uri.EscapeDataString()`.

I guess the single quote makes problems. Using the methods above the single quote should be converted to `%27`.

Comment: So I tried `Uri.EscapeDataString()` & `Uri.EscapeUriString()` but no success. The following three variations don't work `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dürer%27s_Rhinoceros` or `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%BCrer's_Rhinoceros` or `http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FD%C3%BCrer%27s_Rhinoceros`. I can't find System.Web.HttpUtility namespace either.

Comment: @kernanb per http://stackoverflow.com/a/13027407/3101082, add the `System.Web.dll` reference to your project, and you should then be able to use the `HttpUtility` class from the `System.Web` namespace.

Comment: I already can use the `System.web` namespace. There is no `HttpUtility` class. There is a `Http` class but I don't see `UrlEncode` method in there.